# How to get month wise records using knack API?

Tags: php, database, api

Using https://www.knack.com/developer-documentation/ getting the records by filters.But i stucked to get monthwise records.I have following demo which provide last 1 month records.but which operator i need to use to get monthwise records

```
$data = [
          [
            'field' => "field_28",
            'operator' => 'is during the previous',
            'range' => 1,
            'type' => 'months'
           ]
        ];

        $url= 'https://api.knack.com/v1/objects/object_1/records?filters='.rawurlencode(json_encode($data));
```

Comment: You might try `is+during+the+previous` (replace spaces with `+`) as this is what the documentation calls for...

Comment: @JustinT. .above example is working fine so (is+during+the+previous is not issue) .but how i can find by month?

Comment: I don't understand, it already appears to be by month... maybe you are looking for `is during the current`?

Comment: yes but it returns last 1 month record.but i need records by specific month